# issue with json file/ json compatible dictionary being implicitly edited

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

the code i have is for a basic sockets rock paper scissors game, it uses a request based system to ask the server to do things and I've used json files to organize this. it stores a blank json file of the request format so that once the changes to the game have been made the request file can be put back to the default of not making any request. for some reason this file is getting edited despite not being explicitly edited.

i have no clue why this is happening as the "blank_request_jdict" variable isn't even used in the code which edits it. this is only a small chunk of the full code but its the part with the error somewhere within it.

here is the minimized code with the error - added print statements to show what's going on

```
import json

requests_jstring = """{
    "request":{
        "null_request": {
            "active":0
        },
        "setup_new_room": {
            "active":0
        },
        "pick": {
            "active":0,
            "option":"rock"
        },
        "resign": {
            "active":0
        },
        "join_existing_room": {
            "active":0,
            "roomID": 0
        }
    }
}"""
blank_request_jdict = json.loads(requests_jstring)
request_jdict = blank_request_jdict

print("this is what blank requests should be\n", blank_request_jdict)
print("")
print("notice after 'active' every value is 0")
print("")

def request_packer(request_name = "null_request",
                   arg_1=0,
                   arg_2="0,0",
                   arg_3=0,
                   request_jdict = ""):
    """this adds the requests to the request_jdict to then be sent to the server"""
    arg_0=1
    arguments = [arg_0, arg_1, arg_2, arg_3]
    if request_name in request_jdict["request"].keys():
        print("request_name:'",request_name,"' detected - adding to request")
        argnum = 0
        for key in request_jdict["request"][request_name].keys():
            request_jdict["request"][request_name][key]=arguments[argnum]
            argnum = argnum +1
    return request_jdict

request_jdict = request_packer("setup_new_room",request_jdict = request_jdict)

print("but blank jdict is\n", blank_request_jdict)
print("")
print("this blank jdict should never be changed by the code",
      "\nand yet the 'setup new room' 'active' key is edited to 1")
```

Comment: `request_jdict` is `blank_request_jdict` not a copy of it.

Comment: `request_jdict = blank_request_jdict` This does NOT make a copy.  These two names now refer to THE SAME object.

Comment: oh so to make two objects i need to have the lines 
`blank_request_jdict = json.loads(requests_jstring) 
request_jdict = json.loads(requests_jstring)`
at the start and later on how do i set request_jdict to blank_request_jdict without combining them into the same object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import copy
>>> import json
>>>
>>> blank_request_jdict = json.loads('{"foo": "bar"}')
>>> request_jdict = blank_request_jdict
>>>
>>> print(f"id(request_jdict): {id(request_jdict)}")
id(request_jdict): 4417488128
>>> print(f"id(blank_request_jdict): {id(blank_request_jdict)}")
id(blank_request_jdict): 4417488128
>>>
>>> request_jdict_copy = copy.deepcopy(request_jdict)
>>> print(f"id(request_jdict_copy): {id(request_jdict_copy)}")
id(request_jdict_copy): 4415526208
```

`request_jdict` and `request_jdict` are the same thing. There's a few ways to copy objects in python3, but if you only remember one, `copy.deepcopy()` is the one that with the least surprises.

Comment: so if i use `blank_request_jdict = json.loads(requests_jstring)` and then go 
`request_jdict = copy.deepcopy(blank_request_jdict )`
then the 2 jdicts will be treated as completely different objects - and i can write 
`request_jdict = blank_request_jdict` which will change request_jdict to blank_request_jdict without the objects becoming one?

Comment: If you make a copy of `blank_request_jdict`, they won't just be treated as separate objects, they will be separate objects. If you then write `request_jdict = blank_request_jdict`, `request_jdict` will be pointing to the original `blank_request_jdict` again, and they will become the same again. Make a copy of `blank_request_jdict`, then never refer to it again, only update `request_jdict`.

Comment: alright i got it, im just using `request_jdict = copy.deepcopy(blank_request_jdict` to set the request_jdict to the blank version. thanks